# How to connect to localhost using sftp in python

Tags: python, sftp

I just learnt about sftp and want to know how to use sftp to access my localhost. Basically to move files from one path to another path in my localhost using sftp with python. I have tried this,

```
    import pysftp

    cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
    cnopts.hostkeys = None
    myHostname = "localhost"
    myUsername = "user23"
    myPassword = "***********"

    with pysftp.Connection(host=myHostname, username=myUsername, password=myPassword, cnopts=cnopts) 
    as sftp:
        print ("Connection succesfully stablished ... ")
```

But I get an error like -paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Unable to connect to localhost: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
Where am I going wrong?Can anyone suggest

Comment: It could be due to your network settings. Can you connect to the ftp server via browser?

Comment: Oh No, I am not able to connect to ftp server via browswer

Comment: Then check that your server is running correctly, look at the firewall and router configuration. It is probably a server issue. It has nothing to do with your code.